# Incluir un archivo example.php en wordpress creando la función get_example()

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-plugin, wordpress-theme

Lo que busco es incluir un archivo `example.php` que contiene **html**  dentro del archivo wordpress `page.php`; De la misma forma como se incluye el `footer.php` o `header.php` que usan `get_footer()` y `get_header()`.

**En resumen:** Quiero crear la función `get_example()`, para usarlo; pero no tengo nada claro de como crear eso.

**Nota**: si hay otra manera de hacer eso, también coméntenmelo.

Digamos que este es código es de mi archivo `page.php` al cual quiero incluir `example.php` entonces quedaria asi:

```
<?php get_header();?>

<main class="site-main">
   <?php get_example();?>
</main>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

GRACIAS!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La función que podés utilizar es [`get_template_part`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/)

```php
get_template_part( 
  string $slug,
  string $name = null,
  array $args = array() 
)
```

`$slug` es el nombre de la plantilla genérica del "template_part"

`$name` (opcional) es el nombre de la plantilla "especializada"

`$args` (opcional) es para pasarle variables o argumentos a la plantilla

```
<?php get_header();?>

<main class="site-main">
  <?php get_template_part( 'example' );?>
</main>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

buscará el archivo `example.php` para incluirlo en ese lugar, si el archivo no existe no imprime nada. En caso de que tengas un childtheme busca primero en la carpeta del child theme y luego en la carpeta del parent.

`$name` es útil para tener variaciones del mismo fragmento o parte de plantilla especializado para por ejemplo un post type.

Algo así

```
<main class="site-main">
   <?php get_template_part( 'example', 'noticias' );?>
</main>
```

Busca e imprime el primero que encuentre empezando en la carpeta del child theme y luego en el parent theme: `example-noticias.php` si no existe busca `example.php` y si este tampoco existe no imprime nada.

Una forma de extenderlo a varios post types es

```
$post_type = get_post_type();
get_template_part( 'example', $post_type );
```

Si el post type es `page` buscará `example-page.php` si el post type es `noticia` buscará `example-noticia.php`

Comment: excelente!! gracias por tomarte el tiempo de responder.